# How does an Index allocation map (IAM) store data / perform index allocation order scan?

Tags: sql-server, index

Index is SQL server is stored as a B-tree. So an index scan (B-tree scan) is something that will traverse from root to the leaf nodes.

When engine is asked to run a query in the read uncommitted mode, then it does not make use of the B-tree scan. Instead it does an index allocation order scan.

I understand that an Index allocation map (IAM) contains the index and the mapping to which pages have data for that index. I'm not sure whether it is sorted by index or not. How does an Index allocation map (IAM) store data / perform the index allocation scan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Index is SQL server is stored as a B-tree. So an index scan (B-tree scan) is something that will traverse from root to the leaf nodes.

Descending from the root to leaf level is a seeking operation. A scan traverses pages at the leaf level using the next-page pointer (or previous-page pointer for a backward scan) at the leaf level. Pages in a SQL Server index have both next and previous page pointers at every level of the index.

> When engine is asked to run a query in the read uncommitted mode, then it does not make use of the B-tree scan. Instead it does an index allocation order scan.

No, the storage engine has the *option* of using an allocation-order scan when running under read uncommitted isolation, and the data access operator has the *Ordered:False* property. It may or may not use an allocation-order scan at runtime.

> I understand that an Index allocation map (IAM) contains the index and the mapping to which pages have data for that index.

The IAM does not "contain the index". It is a bitmap of extents that belong to a particular object (heap or index partition; in-row, row-overflow, or lob). Each IAM page covers a 4GB range of a single database file for a particular allocation unit.

See [Managing space used by objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide#IAM) in the documentation for a full description. There are too many details to usefully repeat here.

> I'm not sure whether it is sorted by index or not. How does an Index allocation map (IAM) store data / perform the index allocation scan?

Please do read the documentation, but each IAM chain contains IAM pages where a bit is set if the corresponding 64KB extent has data for the current entity. Since each IAM page covers a 4GB range of a single file, the 'order' is file order, at least logically.

SQL Server performs an allocation-order scan starting at the first IAM page, processing extents assigned to the current entity in file order, then following the IAM chain for additional IAM pages as necessary.

The 'file order' nature is where the name 'allocation order' comes from.

Answer (score 4):

> Index is SQL server is stored as a B-tree. So an index scan (B-tree
> scan) is something that will traverse from root to the leaf nodes.

An index is at all levels a linked list of pages. Each page has the address of the next page and the previous page. An index scan means that SQL Server finds the first or last page in the linked list (by traversing the root page to the leaf page, this happens only once) and then follows the linked list until it is satisfied (it could be a full scan, or it can bail out earlier for instance for a TOP).

> When engine is asked to run a query in the read uncommitted mode, then
> it does not make use of the B-tree scan. Instead it does an index
> allocation order scan.

It *can* use the B-Tree. The plan doesn't specify which method, it is *allowing* the storage engine to use both methods. The storage engine decides.

> I understand that an Index allocation map (IAM) contains the index and
> the mapping to which pages have data for that index. I'm not sure
> whether it is sorted by index or not. How does an Index allocation map
> (IAM) store data / perform the index allocation scan?

An IAM page is just like a GAM or SGAM page. It maps 4 GB of data in the database file and has a bit for each extent that the index or heap owns (including up to 8 pages from shared extents). If the index/heap owns data outside of this 4 GB region that the IAM maps, then you have more than one IAM page, and these IAM pages are maintained as a linked list. So, an IAM scan means that SQL Server uses the IAM(s) and visit the extents/pages that are owned by this index/heap.